# Naming convention for function which resets a "static" class

Tags: c++

I need to mock a free function interface in my unit tests. For this reason, I include the mocked function as a static member in a class. I can the save the state of this mock in static class members. I've included the function `free` in this class to free the memory associated with the static members, which gets called at the end of each test case. This function is effectively a destructor. What would be a good name for the constructor equivalent of this function? That is, the function that is called on construction of the test fixture for each test case?

Comment: allocate, initialize etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the function only allocates data structures without initialising them, `allocate` or a variation thereof would seem appropriate (this is also the name used by the C++ STL Allocators).

If the function only initializes data structures allocated elsewhere (for example on the stack or as direct members of another object), `initialize` or a variation thereof would seem appropriate.

If the function does both allocation and initialization, `create` is a common name (prefix) used in C for such functions.